# Sound cloud API not working

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am on developing an application for my Sound Cloud channel. Now API is unavailable.
I got a Client_ID key from Shoutem 
https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/build-react-native-music-app-tutorial-part1/
but also it doesn't work.

This is the client id
`2t9loNQH90kzJcsFCODdigxfp325aq4z`

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the author from the tutorial you were following has terminated the API access. I am getting `error code 401` from the http request.

> This means that we were not able to authenticate you based on the information provided in the request. [Learn more here.](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors)

What you can do is to register your app and generate a `client_id` for yourself, [learn more here.](https://developer.soundcloud.com/)

But it seems like SoundCloud is no longer accepting registration. You may want to contact them personally if you really need to utilise their API, otherwise better off look for some other options.

[image]